# How to sort a column containing DATE in a specified format?

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, date

I have a SQL SELECT statement looking like this:

```
SELECT NAME, ID, TO_CHAR(AUDIT_TIMESTAMP, 'DD-MON-YYYY') AS AUDIT_TIMESTAMP,
TO_CHAR(HIST_TIMESTAMP, 'DD-MON-YYYY') AS HIST_TIMESTAMP
FROM 
MY_TABLE
WHERE 1=1
AND NAME = 'PK_01_123'
AND REVIEWED_FLAG IS NULL
ORDER BY AUDIT_TIMESTAMP DESC
;
```

Values of `MY_TABLE.AUDIT_TIMESTAMP` are coming in format: `28-FEB-09 12.29.23.740174000 AM`

The output table leaves just the `28-FEB-09` part.

Now - the most important thing for me is to sort the AUDIT_TIMESTAMP in the results in a descending order. Is there a way to do this correctly and efficiently? I could format the output like `YYYY-MON-DD` but still - it will just sort it by the year first, and then - by month alfabetically. Is there any way to sort by DATE, so if I have dates like:

```
12-JAN-2014
10-FEB-2015
01-MAR-2013
```

The result of sorting will be:

```
10-FEB-2015
12-JAN-2014
01-MAR-2013
```

I'm using ORACLE database if this helps in any way...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @LalitKumarB, thanks for the explanation. (I'll remove my comment!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with your `ORDER BY` clause. but the fact that your alias matches with the column name used in the order by clause, the actual sorting is based on the **TO_CHAR** value which is a **STRING** and no more a **DATE**.

> Always remember, with DATEs, **TO_CHAR** is only to display the date
>   in desired format which changes the data type from date to string, for
>   any date arithmetic, leave the data type as DATE.

For example, I am sorting the `hiredate` column of standard `EMP` table:

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(hiredate, 'DD-MON-YYYY') hiredate FROM emp ORDER BY hiredate DESC;

HIREDATE
-----------
28-SEP-1981
23-JAN-1982
22-FEB-1981
20-FEB-1981
17-NOV-1981
17-DEC-1980
12-JAN-1983
09-JUN-1981
09-DEC-1982
08-SEP-1981
03-DEC-1981
03-DEC-1981
02-APR-1981
01-MAY-1981

14 rows selected.
```

What happened in above output? The ordering is incorrect, because it sorted the dates as string, thus it sorted based on the **ASCII** value of the string.

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(hiredate, 'DD-MON-YYYY') new_date FROM emp ORDER BY hiredate DESC;

NEW_DATE
-----------
12-JAN-1983
09-DEC-1982
23-JAN-1982
03-DEC-1981
03-DEC-1981
17-NOV-1981
28-SEP-1981
08-SEP-1981
09-JUN-1981
01-MAY-1981
02-APR-1981
22-FEB-1981
20-FEB-1981
17-DEC-1980

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

The above output is correctly sorted because now it sorts based on the **DATE**.

The simple solution is to change your **alias**, and let the **ORDER BY** remain as it is:

```
SELECT NAME,
  ID,
  TO_CHAR(AUDIT_TIMESTAMP, 'DD-MON-YYYY') AS AUD_TIMESTAMP,
  TO_CHAR(HIST_TIMESTAMP, 'DD-MON-YYYY')  AS HIST_TIMESTAMP
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE 1            =1
AND NAME           = 'PK_01_123'
AND REVIEWED_FLAG IS NULL
ORDER BY AUDIT_TIMESTAMP DESC ;
```

Comment: An equally easy solution, and one that doesn't require changing the column name is to use a qualified column reference, either as `<table_name>.<column_name>` or `<table_alias>.<column_name>` in the `sort by` clause.

Comment: @Sentinel Yes, that could be a solution. But the complexity would increase with multiple table joins. The table_name/table_alias should be applied to every column reference, so it is easier to have a different column alias **if it is allowed**. Else, if it is not allowed, then I would go with table_alias and qualified column reference.

Comment: Multiple table joins does not increase the complexity of the order by clause any more than it increases the complexity of the select list itself.

Comment: @Sentinel Well, depends on the requirement. It could be a complex order by clause or a complex select list. In most of the cases per my experience, I agree with you. After all, who wants to add more complexity and overhead of sorting at database level(so your point is completely agreed) :-)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are renaming the column to the same name as the original column.  So, the `ORDER BY` uses the reformatted version.

So, just use a qualified column name in the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT NAME, ID, TO_CHAR(AUDIT_TIMESTAMP, 'DD-MON-YYYY') AS AUDIT_TIMESTAMP,
       TO_CHAR(HIST_TIMESTAMP, 'DD-MON-YYYY') AS HIST_TIMESTAMP
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE 1=1 AND NAME = 'PK_01_123' AND REVIEWED_FLAG IS NULL
ORDER BY MY_TABLE.AUDIT_TIMESTAMP DESC;
```

Comment: You probably mean to use a qualified column reference.  It's the column alias that is causing the problem for the OP.

Comment: @Sentinel . . . The column reference *is* qualified.  I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Your comment "So, just use a column alias" is confusing.  The OP is already using a column alias in the select clause, but not using a qualified column reference in the order by clause, which is the root of his problem.  I'm suggesting that instead of advocating the use of a column alias, you advocate the use of qualified column references in the order by clause.

Comment: @Sentinel . . . That is now "qualified column name".